# Tslint/eslint vs prettier

Tags: eslint, tslint, prettier

Tslint (probably as well as eslint) has a --fix param, that fixes style errors. Is there any reason I should also consider using prettier, other than "prettier has more style rules"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few good reasons why you'd use Prettier over TSLint:

- Prettier is much faster than TSLint at formatting because it doesn't need to run as many rules or use type information.
- Prettier is much more opinionated in its output. That means you get a much more strictly enforced style guide for you. TSLint's `whitespace` rule and related are intentionally not feature-complete with Prettier ([reference](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3548)).
- Prettier reformats code more strictly than TSLint. You have to do a lot less of your own formatting work *(and if others are working on your project, everybody's code will look much more similar)*.

Here's a common approach if you're still interested:

- In your `tslint.json`, use [`tslint-config-prettier`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-prettier) to disable any formatting rules that conflict with Prettier
- Per [Prettier's docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/precommit.html#option-2-pretty-quick-https-githubcom-azz-pretty-quick), use `husky` and `pretty-quick` to auto-run Prettier on all Git commits

Comment: Even if I am still not convinced to use prettier, this is a good answer! Thanks!